# using 2 classes from css and jquery together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to apply a css class and a jquery class together to a checkbox

```
<input type='checkbox' name='something' class='group_ctrl' data-group='group_a' id='checker'>
```

css code class = 'styled' (jquery code combined with css code to style the checkbox)

```
.checkbox, .radio {
    width: 19px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    background: url(images/checkbox.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    clear: left;
/*  float: left; */
}
```

jquery code class = "group_ctrl"

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.group_ctrl').change(function () {
        // gets data-group value and uses it in the outer selector
        // to select the inputs it controls and sets their disabled 
        // property to the negated value of it's checked property 
        $("." + $(this).data("group")).prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    }).change();
});
```

The current html only allows the checkmark to enable or disable other fields as you in can see in the jquery, the css code allows me to style the the checkbox. but the 2 do not go together. i've tried do class"group_ctrl styled" already. but it doesn't work. any suggestions without altering my code on a massive scale?

Comment: You should be able to do this with just one class. If it's only on this specific element. Use an ID. Also, the css you pasted does not effect the checkbox since the class is not set for `.checkbox`

Comment: the script to make the checkbox have an effect is alot of code, that is just a snippet if it. but the css code doesn't seem relevant to the question i don't think

Comment: That's fine, but the fact is, CSS and jQuery both can use the same class name. No point in splitting them unless you have a reason. My point was valid about your CSS. Not sure why you posted the CSS if you thought it was unimportant.

Comment: Please try to clarify your question.  From your comments below, you think it's clear - it's not.  Please note the several comments about "jQuery classes" vs. "CSS classes" - there is no distinction.  A class is a class, and can be used for both styling and scripting simultaneously.  I would add the .group_ctrl class name to your CSS.  you'll get your styling and select the checkbox in your script.

Comment: can you show me an example? in an answer from, this is what i was looking for

Comment: He means `.checkbox, .radio, .group_ctrl { /* rest of your css */`

Answer (score 2):

The CSS you have included applies to anything with a class of checkbox or radio.

```
.checkbox, .radio {
    width: 19px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    background: url(images/checkbox.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    clear: left;
/*  float: left; */
}
```

If this is the correct CSS then you should be applying either checkbox or radio as the class to the fields not styled.

EDIT

if the .checkbox, .radio in your css is to apply to checkboxes and radios, then you need to remove the . i.e.  checkbox, radio, not .checkbox, .radio

CORRECTION - as pointed out to me.. checkbox and radio are not valid tags, it would be input

Comment: you guys are not reading the question properly. class = styled makes the checkbox styled. the css code works just fine. the problem is appling both the css code and the jquery code together. well the checkbox styled includes .css and .js together

Comment: There is no distinction between a "jQuery" class, and a "CSS" class they are the same exact thing.  You can use a class as a selector in jquery rather it has a CSS style associated or not.  Your listed code does not have a styled class in it at all  `.styled { css:works }`

Comment: Why the down vote?  If you are not getting the answer you seek, perhaps ask the right question.

Comment: i didn't down vote you, only people with 125 rep can downvote

Comment: I suspect you were downvoted because of what you said in the edit (`checkbox, radio` is not a proper selector because there are no tags with those names). And @Sickest, your question is extremely unclear...

Comment: Ok.. class="class1 class2 class3" will work... HOWEVER in some cases i have seen that you have to get pretty specific in your css definition.....  i.e.  checkbox.class1 { display:block } rather then just .class1 {display: block} especially when multiple CSS styles are applied at once.

Comment: NOONE is understanding what you are asking for... i suspect because you do not yourself.